# Why could Sai perform Ninja Art: Super Beast Scroll if he had no emotions?

Tags: naruto

In *Boruto*, we figure out that losing passion towards art will make you lose the ability to perform [Ninja Art: Super Beast Scroll](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Super_Beast_Imitating_Drawing).However, Sai had completely suppressed all emotions when he came out of the Foundation.

So, how was he able to use this jutsu? I think passion is also an emotion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [wiki](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Super_Beast_Imitating_Drawing):

> In the anime, for the drawings to retain stability upon emerging, the user's emotional state must have a true passion for them (art). Otherwise, the drawings will immediately splatter.

It is true that Sai didn't had emotions or FWIW, he suppressed them but he didn't lose his passion for art. In fact, it was the one thing he held onto from his early childhood with his brother until the present. His passion for art is what gives him the ability to use the Super Beast Scroll jutsu.

Comment: Did you just copy pasted from quora? My point is passion is also an emotion. So if he had  passion, he had emotions.

Comment: @BhavyaGupta I think the point he's trying to make is that while the Foundation teaches the complete *erase* of your emotions, Sai had held on to his passion to draw/write, and if you consider passion an emotion, then *no*, he didn't erase all of them. His passion to draw was critical for his jutsu and thus he did not erase it. And he would've used a blockquote (as he did when he quoted the wiki) if he had copied and pasted from Quora.

Comment: @Bhavya 1. Passion and emotions might go hand-in-hand [but they are two different things](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/passion-vs-emotion-anbu-ganapathi-muppidathi). 2. I might have copied some sentences from Quora because the wordings is what I was looking for (I would have wrote the same thing tbh) but I didn't copied the entire thing and blockquoted and thus I didn't referenced it "from Quora". 3. If you looked it up yourself and found that Quora article, why did you went through the trouble of asking here? If you got the answer from there, you should have self-answer it.

Comment: If you are not satisfied with the answer, I can delete it.

Comment: @FumikageTokoyami Your answer is now accepted, I'd assume he'd be satisfied with it. What I think confused him is thinking that passion is an emotion. Good answer tho, +1